# CSS media option works, but doesn't make any change

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This CSS works:

```css
@media (max-width:1023px) {
    html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width:1024px;    
    }
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;
    }    
}

@media (min-width:1024px)  {
    html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

So, for small resolutions there is `min-width: 1024px;` option in browser output: but this doesn't change anything - still on small resolutions browser tries to put whole document in current resolution limits.

What is with 1024px resolution width:

[image]

What is with small screen:

[image]

That's why I want to use width for small resolution - to be page displayed with 1024px's width, and visible part on these screens will be theis resolution with scrolling lefr-right

Comment: What do you mean by: "it works"?

Comment: I'm confused... you're forcing small screens to have a big-screen layout?

Comment: I mean, browser detects it ( I can see it in element inspection), but, as I sad, still tries to put whole document in 640px's

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi, just quick fix for small resolutions, 1024px is minimal width, with which page doesn't become a mess

Comment: So why do you need a media query for this at all? If you just leave the page as is and DON'T include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`, the site should work as is. If not, there's something in your code that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi, damn language barrier. Now I will provide a screenshot, may be this will help me explain

Comment: That might be helpful. Sorry we're having trouble communicating clearly!

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi, added screenshots

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code. If you have the width set to 1024px, you shouldn't need min-width at all and stuff shouldn't be shifting and smushing like that.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the code posted works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/87mMW/. @JoeHalfFace, what browser are you using?

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi, I wonder may be that's online tester issue, not my CSS, it is possible?

Comment: Definitely possible. What happens when you just drag your browser window in?

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi, browser resize is ok, but, does it equal to smaller resolution?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace: yes. “Smaller resolution” mean “fewer pixels” (i.e. 1024x768 is bigger resolution, 640x480 is smaller resolution). So you can simulate 640x480 by dragging your browser window in so it’s 640 pixels wide. JSFiddle has put your code inside an iframe that (in my browser) is 627 pixels wide. And, as you can see using Chrome’s Web Inspector, the `<body>` element is still 1024 pixels wide.

Answer (score 1):

So, you’re saying that even though you’ve set a minimum width of 1024 pixels on the `<body>` element for browser viewports narrower than that, your `<body>` element isn’t being rendered any wider than the browser viewport?

Odd. Works for me in Chrome 27:

- http://jsfiddle.net/87mMW/

What browser are you using? [Media queries aren’t supported in IE ≦8, Firefox ≦3, and Safari ≦3.1](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%40media_%28min-width%29).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, you can remove the media queries altogether and just use this:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1024px;
}
```

To avoid repeating yourself, though, a more cleaned up version looks like this:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width: 1024px;
}
```